# JavaScript Compare ERRO

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando passar um for para validar uma lista que preciso porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que funcione e não entendi o porque ainda.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$('#aprovados').click( function(){
  $.getJSON($('#listeditappjobs').attr("data-list-app-my-jobs-url"),
    function(data){
      if (data){
        var apps = data.data
        console.log(apps[0])
        var infojob = data.datas
        console.log(infojob)
        var aprovados = []
        for(i = 0; i < apps.length; i++){
         if (infojob.distance >= apps[i].distance  &&
             infojob.xp <= apps[i].years_xp &&
             infojob.salary_min <= apps[i].pre_salary  &&
             infojob.salary_max >= apps[i].pre_salary)
            {aprovados.push(apps[i]); }
               };
        console.log(aprovados)
      }else{alert("LISTA vazia")
    }},
);
});
```

O Que eu tenho de retorno é:

```
Object { distance: 1, escolaridade: "TecnologoCursando", user: "jhonatan@teste.com", pre_salary: "1500.12", years_xp: 3 }

Object { distance: 2, xp: 3, salary_max: "1500.01", salary_min: "200.00" }
Array []
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está comparando números como strings:

```
infojob.salary_min <= apps[i].pre_salary
       |                     |
     "200.00"            "1500.12"

infojob.salary_max >= apps[i].pre_salary
       |                     |
     "1500.01"            "1500.12"
```

Use `parseFloat()` para convertê-los em números:

```
if (infojob.distance >= apps[i].distance  &&
    infojob.xp <= apps[i].years_xp &&
    parseFloat(infojob.salary_min) <= parseFloat(apps[i].pre_salary)  &&
    parseFloat(infojob.salary_max) >= parseFloat(apps[i].pre_salary))
   { aprovados.push(apps[i]); }
```

No entanto, se observar, esse `if` não irá ser verdadeiro porque a última condição é *false*:

```
parseFloat(infojob.salary_max) >= parseFloat(apps[i].pre_salary)
                  |                                 |
               1500.01                           1500.12
```

`1500.01` não é `>=` do que `1500.12`.

---

Exemplo onde todas as condições são verdadeiras:

```js
var data = {
   data: [{
      distance: 1,
      escolaridade: "TecnologoCursando",
      user: "jhonatan@teste.com",
      pre_salary: "1500.12",
      years_xp: 3
   }],
   datas: {
      distance: 2,
      xp: 3,
      salary_max: "1500.12",
      salary_min: "200.00"
   }
}

var apps = data.data;
console.log(apps[0]);
var infojob = data.datas;
console.log(infojob);
var aprovados = [];
for(i = 0; i < apps.length; i++){
   if (infojob.distance >= apps[i].distance  &&
       infojob.xp <= apps[i].years_xp &&
       parseFloat(infojob.salary_min) <= parseFloat(apps[i].pre_salary)  &&
       parseFloat(infojob.salary_max) >= parseFloat(apps[i].pre_salary))
   { aprovados.push(apps[i]); }
}
console.log(aprovados);
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, me ajudou muito!
...referente aos dados, eu tenho mais um monte eu coloquei ai só exemplo pra conseguir explicar mais ou menos o que precisa rs